# Setting the image taken from the gallery to the UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

The problem am facing is placing the picture i choose from the gallery into the`UIImageView` (imageChosen).

The code runs fine without any errors but the picture i chose is not set to the "imageChosen"

here is my code

```
class postChoices: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageChosen: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func gallery(sender: AnyObject) {

        var image = UIImagePickerController()
        //image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image2: UIImageView!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
      //  let selectedImage : UIImageView = image
        imageChosen.image = image2.image

    }


}
```

Comment: @adnan didn't work, am adding the imageChosen inside the same view, self.view

Comment: @adnan okay, am checking now

Comment: @adnan i saw this code here http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/user-interaction-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller-swift/ , all what i want it so put the picture in the imageView, without creating the buttons, thanks

Comment: @adnan okay, i will try now

Comment: @adnan there is no UIImagePickerDelegateMethode O_o

Comment: I have added an answer . Hope it will make a sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Complete solution with delegates and image handling    

     import UIKit

        class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

            @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            @IBAction func gallery(sender: AnyObject) {

                if UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.PhotoLibrary) != nil {
                    picker.allowsEditing = false
                    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
                    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    noCamera()
                }

            }
            func noCamera(){
                let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera", message: "Sorry, Gallery is not accessible.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: nil)
                alertVC.addAction(okAction)
                presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                picker.delegate = self   //the required delegate to get a photo back to the app.
             }

            //MARK: - Delegates
            //What to do when the picker returns with a photo
            func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
                var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
                myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit //3
                myImageView.image = chosenImage //4
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) //5
            }
            //What to do if the image picker cancels.
            func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

[Demo Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwt464ia61p3din/Gallery%20Demo.zip?dl=0)

Comment: use imageChosen instead of myImageView . Just check logic , variable names doesn't matter

Comment: do you know how can i change to another view, after i chose an image from the gallery, i mean, are there a way of doing it, maybe inside segue or different function

Comment: you can cal a method where you setting image. push view controller or use segues as per your logic

Answer (score 2):

Several problems.

If you look at the docs the method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` was deprecated in iOS **3.0**.

It's a fair bet it's not even being called. 
(You have the line that sets up your view controller as the delegate commented out, so the image picker won't call your delegate methods.

In your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` method you have image2 defined as a UIImageView. It's not, it's a UIImage.

You should un-comment the line `image.delegate = self`.

You should implement the method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` instead of `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:`.

You probably also need to add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to the definition of your view controller class so the compiler knows that your view controller conforms to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: when i take out the comment in the line  image.delegate=self, an error showing, saying Cannot assign a value of type 'PostChoice' to a value of type 'protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

Comment: Ok, then you need to add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to your class like: `class myVC: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. That tells the compiler that your class conforms to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

```
    - (void) makeUIImagePickerControllerForCamera:(BOOL)camera {

         UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         picker.delegate = self;
         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

         [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil]];

         [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        // Dismiss the picker
        [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Get the image from the result
    UIImage* image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    myUIImage.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code helped me with swift 3.0**

```
internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        billImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        billImageView.image = pickedImage
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0
in this code you have select both option camera and Gallary**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
class HostVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{    
@IBOutlet weak var imgHostProfile:UIImageView!
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

 @IBAction func btnChangeprofileTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {


        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Choose profile picture from Camera or Gallery", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                                self.Cemara()
                            } else {
                                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) -> Void in
                                    if granted == true {
                                        self.Cemara()
                                    } else {
                                        self.showalert(strMessage: Validation.kCameraAccess)
                                    }
                                })
                            }

                    }
                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose from Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()
                            imagepicker.delegate = self
                            imagepicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

                            self.present(imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }))

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in}))

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


    }

    func Cemara()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil
            {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                self.noCamera()
            }
        }
    }

    //======================================================================
    //                  MARK: -  Camera  Code
    //======================================================================

    func noCamera()
    {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice]
        {
            for device in devices
            {
                if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo))
                {
                    if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)
                    {
                        captureDevice = device
                        if captureDevice != nil
                        {
                            print("Capture device found")
                            beginSession()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //======================================================================
    //                  MARK: - Camera Capture Start Session Code Here
    //======================================================================

    func beginSession()
    {
        do
        {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)
            {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        guard let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) else
        {
            print("no preview layer")
            return
        }
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
        self.view.addSubview(imgHostProfile)


    }

    //======================================================================
    //                  MARK: - Gallary Code
    //======================================================================

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        if let imagedata = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            self.imgHostProfile.image = imagedata
            print(imagedata)


        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```